# Ionic 3 - One/Two-Way Binding Usage

Tags: ionic-framework, binding, ionic3, two-way-binding

The purpose of the app is to check whether a student is absent or present. For testing purposed. I have this code on my app.

### HTML

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>
    Students
  </ion-list-header>

<ion-item>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="attendance.studentName[0]" type="text"></ion-input>
  <ion-select item-end [(ngModel)]="attendance.status[0]">
    <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="attendance.studentName[1]" type="text"></ion-input>
  <ion-select item-end [(ngModel)]="attendance.status[1]">
    <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

### TS

```
attendance: any[] = [{
    'studentName': [],
    'status': []
}]
```

Current, I am using two-way binding "[(ngModel)]" for the input and select tags. But when I type and select an option, both of these are being edited. But when I use one-way binding "[ngModel]". The problem of both inputs and select options being edited at the same time is gone. But I get nothing on console.log

Comment: What is this @MJ Isip first you accept my answer then you accept another answer

Comment: It's all good now. Don't know why/how it changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all edit in `.ts` file**

```
  public attendance: any[] = [
    {
      studentName: 'Alice',
      status: 'whatever'
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Bob',
      status: 'whatever'
    }

  ];
```

**Need to change in `.html` using `*ngFor`**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>
    Students
  </ion-list-header>

  <div *ngFor="let student of attendance">

    <ion-item >
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="student.studentName" type="text"></ion-input>
      <ion-select item-end [(ngModel)]="student.status">
        <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

  </div>


</ion-list>
```

**Here is output image** [image: output image]

Comment: if you get undefined then knock me .... or without checking you give me accept .... i will execute all code with output.....

Comment: If you got undefined on addAttendance(student) then update your code i will resolve it ......

Answer (score 0):

You are targetting the same object in each `ion-item`. You have one class property named `attendance`.

Whenever Angular assigns a value to `attendance.studentName`, it overwrites whatever value was previously set, or the default, initial value (an empty array).

Each ion-input and `ion-select` must target a distinct object in your component class.

The typical way would be to use an array of objects, and then loop through the array in your HTML template (with *ngFor).

The array could be like :

```
public attendance: any[] = [
    {
        studentName: 'Alice',
        status: 'whatever'
    },
    {
        studentName: 'Bob',
        status: 'whatever'
    }
]
```

Comment: Still couldnt get the value.. Here's what I did..

    public attendance: any[] = [
      {
        studentName: [],
        status: [],
      }
    ]

 then I set [(ngModel)]="attendance.studentName[0]" and for the status

What am I missing?

Comment: First, please leave the question as originally posted, otherwise it is impossible to understand the answers and comments.
Second: it would be `[(ngModel)]="attendance[0].studentName"` because `attendance` is the array in this case